# Without directly evaluting, show that the determinant of $A = 0$

Tags: matrices

> Without directly evaluting, show that 
>   $det \left[
>        \begin{array}{ccc}
>          b + c & c + a & b + a \\
>            a & b & c \\
>            1 & 1 & 1 
>        \end{array}
>      \right]
> =0$

I am stuck on this one. I can only do this by evuating.

Things that I know:
1) Square matrix $A$ with two proportional rows or columns as a $det(A) = 0$
2) Square matrix $A$ has $det(A)=0$ if it has a row or column of zeros.

Can anyone help?
Thanks.

Comment: Hint:  adding the first two rows gives a multiple of the third.

Comment: Ok @lulu. So you're saying if I had $R2$ to $R1$, then I will have $(a + b +c)\times R3$. Is that correct? I like this. Thankyou.

Comment: I like your answer @lulu. If you can put that as an answer I can then accept it.

Comment: I'll post something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The row vectors are linearly dependent.

Specifically, denoting the row vectors as $$\vec r_1=(b+c,a+c,a+b)\quad \vec r_2=(a,b,c)\quad \vec r_3=(1,1,1)$$  then we have $$\vec r_1+\vec r_2=(a+b+c)\,\vec r_3$$

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possibility: For a fixed value of $a,b$, $\det(A)$ is a degree two polynomial in $c$. It is obviously $0$ for $c=0,a,b$, and hence the polynomial is identically $0$. (Unless $a=b$, $a=0$, etc, but then you can use the same reasoning with the other variables).

Comment: Thanks for your input @ThomasGrubb.